# Wordpress: check for custom user role in frontend

Tags: php, wordpress, user-roles

I simply want to display some message when a user has a **custom** user role. It works with native user roles, but not with custom ones. Here is my code:

```
<?php
$user_ID = get_current_user_ID();
$user = new WP_User( $user_ID );
$current_user = $user->roles[0];

if( $current_user == 'client' ){
   echo 'hello client';
} else {
   // do nothing
}
?>
```

Any help is welcome, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this :

```
if ( is_user_logged_in() )
{
    global $current_user;
    $user_role = $current_user->roles[0];

    if($user_role == 'client')
    {
    // do something
    }
}
```

`is_user_logged_in()` is used to check whether user is logged in or not

Comment: Turns out I made a mistake in creating the custom user roles. Still, your way is much better/cleaner, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The examples above are problematic if the User has more than one Role set, as the code only checks the first Role the user has set.

Ideally, you should be checking if any of the User's Roles match the custom role:

```
if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
    global $current_user;

    if( in_array('YOUR_CUSTOM_ROLE',  $current_user->roles) ) {
        echo 'User has Custom Role';
    } else {
        echo 'User does not have Custom Role';
    }
}
```